Infinite loop in Spring Boot when entering incorrect credentials for Active Directory authentication
I'm working on a Spring Boot application with Spring Security and Active Directory for authentication and I've set up a virtual machine with Windows Server 2019 to connect to my Active Directory. The authentication works find when I enter valid credentials, however, when I enter incorrect credentials I encounter an infinite loop of errors, so here’s my WebSecurityConfig:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private static final String DOMAIN = "xxxxxx.net";
    private static final String URL = "ldap://xxxxxxxx:389/";

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(cors -> cors
                        .configurationSource(request -> {
                            CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
                            corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:4200"));
                            corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("POST", "PUT", "GET", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
                            corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Content-Type"));
                            corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
                            return corsConfiguration;
                        }))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("auth/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(login -> login.permitAll())
        .sessionManagement(session ->
                        session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED));
        return http.build();
    }



    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);

        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adProvider =
                new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(DOMAIN, URL);
        adProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        adProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);

        auth.authenticationProvider(adProvider);

        return auth.build();
    }
}

Here's my controller
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody Login login, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken =
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(login.getUser(), login.getPassword());
            authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

            Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(authToken);

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);

            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            session.setAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, SecurityContextHolder.getContext());

            return ResponseEntity.ok().body("{\"message\": \"Login Successful\"}");
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("{\"error\": \"Login Failed: " + e.getMessage() + "\"}");
        }
    }

}

This is the error
2024-06-21T14:55:11.425-05:00 DEBUG 21880 --- \[waza\] \[nio-8080-exec-4\] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing OPTIONS /auth/login
2024-06-21T14:55:11.428-05:00 DEBUG 21880 --- \[waza\] \[nio-8080-exec-9\] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /auth/login
2024-06-21T14:55:11.428-05:00 DEBUG 21880 --- \[waza\] \[nio-8080-exec-9\] o.s.s.w.session.SessionManagementFilter  : Request requested invalid session id 3483544F478CB1A816B1EE2D674EC902
2024-06-21T14:55:11.429-05:00 DEBUG 21880 --- \[waza\] \[nio-8080-exec-9\] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /auth/login
2024-06-21T14:55:11.432-05:00 DEBUG 21880 --- \[waza\] \[nio-8080-exec-9\] ctiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider : Authentication for am123@xxxxxx.net failed:javax.naming.AuthenticationException: \[LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090439, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v4563 \]
2024-06-21T14:55:11.432-05:00  INFO 21880 --- \[waza\] \[nio-8080-exec-9\] ctiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider : Active Directory authentication failed: Supplied password was invalid
2024-06-21T14:55:11.433-05:00 DEBUG 21880 --- \[waza\] \[nio-8080-exec-9\] ctiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider : Authentication for am123@xxxxxx.net failed:javax.naming.AuthenticationException: \[LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090439, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v4563 \]
2024-06-21T14:55:11.433-05:00  INFO 21880 --- \[waza\] \[nio-8080-exec-9\] ctiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider : Active Directory authentication failed: Supplied password was invalid

I know that are invalid credentials but the error appears a hundred of times, and after this, the console show me this
2024-06-21T14:55:12.908-05:00 ERROR 21880 --- \[waza\] \[nio-8080-exec-9\] o.a.c.c.C.\[.\[.\[/\].\[dispatcherServlet\]    : Servlet.service() for servlet \[dispatcherServlet\] in context with path \[\] threw exception \[Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.StackOverflowError\] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.scanIPv4Address(URI.java:3453) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseIPv4Address(URI.java:3493) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3541) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3640) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3592) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.net.URI.\<init\>(URI.java:600) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:869) \~\[na:na\]

and a lot of info that i cant't understand,
Finally these are my dependencies
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>13.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

Im using spring boot 3.3.0 and i've tried with spring boot 3.2.5 and 3.2.6 and is the same error.
I was debbuging the app and the error happens on this line
Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(authToken);
I also tried with the default login provided by spring security, but nothing works, please help, i don't know why this happens.
Appreciate your help
